# Show XHR's initiator in Firefox Dev Tools

Tags: firefox

Does anybody know how to show an XHR's initiator in Firefox Dev Tools just like you can in Chrome?

I find this very useful and cannot seem to find a similar feature in Firefox.

Here's an example of it looks like in Chrome:

[image: POST initiator in Chrome]

Answer (score 2):

Rightclick on the table header. Then activate the "Initiator" column.
[image]